# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\Program Files\XAMPP\htdocs\lookup.php on line 116

Tags: php

So I have been trying to get this search script to run locally with XAMPP and that's the error I have been getting, any tips? I don't know much about programming hence why I'm asking, I got the script from a public source and was just trying to set it up locally.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Search Engine</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .footertext{
                position:center;
                bottom:0;
            }
            body {
                background-color: #202020;
            }
            body,td,th {
                color: #CCC;
                font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            }
            .searchbox {
                font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
                font-size: 18px;
                color: #CCC;
                background-color: #333;
                border: 1px solid #CCC;
                padding-left: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <a href=""><img border="0" src="" alt ="logo"></a>
            <br>
            <br><a href="/dblookup.php/"><b><u>Search Again</u></b></a>
            <br>How to use: <br>Input search term and click search.
        </div>

        <div align="center">
        <?php

        $fname = strlen(htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']));

        if (isset($_POST['text'])){
            $directory = "";

            //get all image files with a .jpg extension.
            $images = glob($directory . "*.txt");

            //print each file name
            foreach($images as $image)
            {
                if($fname<3)
                {
                    echo "You must have atleast 4 characters in your search, Sorry.";
                    return;
                }

                $file = $image;
                $searchfor = $_POST['text'];

                // the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
                // get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
                $contents = file_get_contents($file);
                // escape special characters in the query
                $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
                // finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
                $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*$/mi";
                //require "sanitize.php";

                // search, and store all matching occurences in $matchess
                if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
                    echo "<br><br>Found matches in $file:<br />";

                    //$nigga = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $matches);
                    //vv this part
                    $gud = implode("\n", $matches[0]);
                    //#####################^ htmlspecialchars($matches[0]) -> But it doesnt output anything..
                    //#This part ^^
                    echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($gud));
                }else{
                    echo "";
                }
            }
        } else {
        ?>
        </div>
        <form action='' method='post'>
            <div align="center">Search: <br><input name='text' type='text' class="searchbox"> 
                <input type='submit' class="searchbox" value='Search'>
            </div>
        </form>

        <? } ?>
        <div class="footertext">
            <br><br><br>
            <center>Lookup: <a href="">Lookup</center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This error is typical of an unclosed brace somewhere in your code.

Comment: You need to use `break;` instead of `return;` in the loop

Answer (score 4):

It appears that your php configuration is not allowing [short_open_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Replace the following line:

```
<? } ?>
```

with:

```
<?php } ?>
```

Here is the working version of your code after the fix in phpfiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8sm-b3g

Comment: Chicha, Vee you are right. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** PHP short tags are deprecated in newer version.

change this line

```
<? } ?>
```

to

```
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP's settings, the directive short_open_tags is not enabled.
If this directive is enabled, PHP can run with the tags: `<? ?>`.
Therefore, it will show error on `<? ?>` and must require `<?php ?>`.
If you want your file to run with `<? ?>`, go to your `php.ini`file.
And uncomment the line:

`short_open_tag = Off`

change it to:

`short_open_tag = On`

And you code will work.